# Android not starting Activity when started from a JobScheduler

Tags: android, xamarin, installation, service, scheduler

This is my issue.

1. I have a main activity that triggers an app install if a specific apk is available. Which runs fine and shows the install dialog etc. so all good.
2. Within the main activity I setup a job scheduler with a job info and schedule it to run every 30 mins. within the job I check for the apk, if present runs the installer and renames the installed apk.

The issue I have is that the install process (both use the same) works 100% from the main activity but when it runs from the jobscheduler the install intent is never shown.

Everything else in the jobscheduler process runs fine though. ie. file rename etc.

I've setup permissions in the manifest file.

```
<service android:name=".MyInstallService" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
```

Permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_PACKAGE_SIZE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_DELETE_PACKAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTANT_APP_FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Code:

```
    var fileProviderAuthorities = "my.files.provider";
    Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(path);
    Android.Net.Uri apkUri = AndroidX.Core.Content.FileProvider.GetUriForFile(Android.App.Application.Context, fileProviderAuthorities, file);

    var intent = new Android.Content.Intent("android.intent.action.INSTALL_PACKAGE");
    intent.SetData(apkUri);
    intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
    intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);

    Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Did you start the activity from the JobScheduler background and what was the android version of the testing device? For the android 10 and higher, there are some limits for starting an activity from the background. You can check the [official document](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts)

Comment: yeah, I've started the activity from a jobschedule in the background. Found something I had missed with some experimentation today and it looks like the app needs to request the 'appear on top' permission for the activity to show. I set that and it now shows. So I've added a permission check in the app to display the permission toggle. I'm using android 11